# shopware6 localhost demo page not working

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

After successfully installing shopware on my machine, i was able to setup and open admin panel.
[image]

but than if i open demo home page, this is what i see:
[image]

what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are missing the CSS and JS files for the storefront.

Try running the following commands in the root dir of your installation to install and build the storefront javascript

```bash
composer run init:js
composer run build:js:storefront
```

Then assign the default theme and compile it again:

```bash
bin/console theme:change --all Storefront
bin/console assets:install
```

If that doesn't help, you should try to figure out why the storefront assets cannot be loaded. In the browser console, you should see some requests for `.js` and `.css` that are failing. Maybe the configuration for your public filesystem is wrong, and the asset files stored there are not publicly accessible in your setup?

Refer to the [docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/filesystem.html#filesystem) for more info regarding the configuration for the Filesystem.

Comment: So first i opened browser console and i didnt see any errors or even warnings.

Than i tried to run a composer command that you suggested, please take a look at response to see what error i got.

Seems like i am missing some files/folders, but i dont know how is that possible... i am sorry if i am missing something obvious, i am stressed with shopware installation...

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Solved after deleting and fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

edo@158-EDIOSM-LT:~/platform$ composer run init:js

> export PROJECT_ROOT="$PWD"; cd src/Administration/Resources/app/administration; export PATH="$PWD/node_modules/.bin/:$PATH"; "$PROJECT_ROOT"/bin/exec-with-env  'npm' 'clean-install' '--no-audit' '--prefer-offline'
> PHP Warning:  require(/home/edo/platform/bin/../vendor/autoload.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/edo/platform/bin/exec-with-env on line 16
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/edo/platform/bin/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/edo/platform/bin/exec-with-env:16
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}
> thrown in /home/edo/platform/bin/exec-with-env on line 16
> Script export PROJECT_ROOT="$PWD"; cd src/Administration/Resources/app/administration; export PATH="$PWD/node_modules/.bin/:$PATH"; "$PROJECT_ROOT"/bin/exec-with-env  handling the npm:admin:bin event returned with error code 255
> Script @npm:admin:bin npm was called via npm:admin
> Script @npm:admin clean-install --no-audit --prefer-offline was called via init:js